# Best way to call an IEnumerator from a static method in Unity with C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Editor: Unity - C#

can you give me some informations and tipps how i can start an IEnumerator from a static method.
What I know so far are the following options:

A): Make the Method (METHOD_1) that calls the IEnumerator non static and then search the script like this

```
FindObjectOfType<Scriptname>().METHOD_1();
```

B): Use MonoBehaviour to start the Coroutine

```
Scriptname.METHOD_1(this);
```

---

```
public static void METHOD_1(MonoBehaviour StartThisStatic)
{
    StartThisStatic.StartCoroutine(Test());
}
public static IEnumerator Test()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
}
```

C): Use instance in awake/start

What is the best option in terms of performance and stability?
Can you explain a little background knowledge to me in a simple way?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try to avoid `FindObjectOfType`, its costly to use outside scene initialization.

Comment: You can also make a nested  `Monobehaviour` class when you don't really need a coroutine manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class CoroutineController : MonoBehaviour
{

    static CoroutineController _singleton;
    static Dictionary<string,IEnumerator> _routines = new Dictionary<string,IEnumerator>(100);

    [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod( RuntimeInitializeLoadType.BeforeSceneLoad )]
    static void InitializeType ()
    {
        _singleton = new GameObject($"#{nameof(CoroutineController)}").AddComponent<CoroutineController>();
        DontDestroyOnLoad( _singleton );
    }

    public static Coroutine Start ( IEnumerator routine ) => _singleton.StartCoroutine( routine );
    public static Coroutine Start ( IEnumerator routine , string id )
    {
        var coroutine = _singleton.StartCoroutine( routine );
        if( !_routines.ContainsKey(id) ) _routines.Add( id , routine );
        else
        {
            _singleton.StopCoroutine( _routines[id] );
            _routines[id] = routine;
        }
        return coroutine;
    }
    public static void Stop ( IEnumerator routine ) => _singleton.StopCoroutine( routine );
    public static void Stop ( string id )
    {
        if( _routines.TryGetValue(id,out var routine) )
        {
            _singleton.StopCoroutine( routine );
            _routines.Remove( id );
        }
        else Debug.LogWarning($"coroutine '{id}' not found");
    }
    public static void StopAll () => _singleton.StopAllCoroutines();
    
}
```

Then:

```
CoroutineController.Start( Test() );
```

You can also stop specific coroutines here by giving them labels:

```
CoroutineController.Start( Test() , "just a test" );

// <few moments later, meme>

CoroutineController.Stop( "just a test" );
```

Comment: thank you very much it works exactly as I wanted it to....

can you explain a bit to me what exactly happens in your script?

Comment: To start a coroutine you need a reference to a Monobehaviour. This class provides that reference as a static field

Comment: static field `_singleton` is being auto-magically initialized in `InitializeType` method thanks to `[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod()]` attribute

Answer (score 1):

My solution to starting the Coroutines from places that can't do this is making a Singleton CoroutineManager. I then use this CoroutineManager to invoke these Coroutines from places like ScriptableObjects. You can also use it to cache WaitForEndOfFrame or WaitForFixedUpdate so you don't need to create new ones every time.

Answer (score 0):

To better understand the concept look at this absolutely bare-minimum version of CoroutineController class. It's just a field and a method, that's all:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class CoroutinePawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static CoroutinePawn Instance { get; private set; }

    [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.BeforeSceneLoad)]
    static void InitializeType ()
    {
        Instance = new GameObject($"#{nameof(CoroutinePawn)}").AddComponent<CoroutinePawn>();
        DontDestroyOnLoad( Instance );
    }
}
```

And because this `Instance` static field gives you a reference to an existing `MonoBehaviour` (GameObject) - you can start coroutines manually from anywhere:

```
CoroutinePawn.Instance.StartCoroutine( Test() );
```